# Is it possible, in a Haskell source code, to import a module that has already been compiled in an object file (.o)?

Tags: haskell, shared-libraries

Suppose that i have compiled a module called `ModuleA`. The GHC compiler generated the `.o` and `.hi` files.

Now i want to import `ModuleA`  in another source file without re-compiling it or installing a new package, i.e. i want the GHC to detect that `ModuleA` was already compiled and is stored in an .o file.

Is it possible? how?

Until now, i tried to set some GHC flags in order to look at the directory that the `.o` and `.hi` files are stored, but the compilation fails because GHC can not find the interface of `ModuleA`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GHC should do this for modules in the current directory automatically:

```
$ echo "module ModuleA where { a :: Int ; a = 1 }" > ModuleA.hs
$ ghc -c ModuleA.hs
$ echo "module Main where { import ModuleA ; main :: IO () ; main = print a }" > ModuleB.hs
$ ghc ModuleB.hs -o ModuleB
[2 of 2] Compiling Main             ( ModuleB.hs, ModuleB.o )
Linking ModuleB ...
$ ./ModuleB
1
```

(Note the lack of "Compiling ModuleA" line above)

It should only recompile imported modules in the local directory if the source file has changed since
it was last compiled:

```
$ echo "module ModuleA where { a :: Int ; a = 2 }" >! ModuleA.hs
$ ghc ModuleB.hs -o ModuleB
[1 of 2] Compiling ModuleA          ( ModuleA.hs, ModuleA.o )
Linking ModuleB ...
$ ./ModuleB
2
```

(Note the "Compiling ModuleA" line above, and the lack of "Compiling Main" line)

The same goes for other locations on the import path:

```
$ rm ModuleA.*
$ mkdir foo
$ echo "module ModuleA where { a :: Int ; a = 3 }" > foo/ModuleA.hs
$ ghc -c foo/ModuleA.hs
$ ghc ModuleB.hs -o ModuleB -ifoo
Linking ModuleB ...
$ ./ModuleB
3
```

Comment: Considering the last code, is it possible to create the executable for `ModuleB` if `ModuleA.hs` is moved to a  random directory? i.e. Is it always necessary to have the source code of `ModuleA` to compile `ModuleB.hs`? e.g. the following commands does not compile `ModuleB`: 1) `ghc -c ModuleA.hs` 2) `mv ModuleA.hs foo2` 3)`ghc ModuleB.hs -o ModuleB`. The error is: `Failed to load interface for ModuleA`.

Comment: @andregps : Is there any reason you don't want to wrap ModuleA in a package? Building, installing, and using packages is easy.

Comment: I am just researching what is the most flexible solution to update a library in Haskell, so that other developers can use the modules defined on it. Using packages, as far as i know, you need to reinstall it everytime it changes. I think that if i could only update the `.o` and `.hs` files, the update is easier. Is this kind of update possible?

Comment: @andregps: ...what is updating `.o` files if not a form of reinstalling? packages can be installed globally to be accessible to multiple users, and they have the benefit of versioning, making it evident when the API changes.

Comment: i agree about packages. But, just to make it clear, i think the answer to the question i did on my previous comment is: in order to import `ModuleA` without installing its package, it is necessary to have its source code (`ModuleA.hs`) on GHC's include directories when compiling. Is this answer right?

Comment: I don't know. I haven't been able to make it compile w/o the `.hs` file, but I can't say that it can't be done.